# Code Of Block Execute Multiple Time in jsf and jboss server

Tags: java, jsf, jboss

i am working on big web application which is developed in java, using jsf framework, running on jboss server.

I face a problem: I have a function in which we call some soap web services.
This works fine in normal situation,  but sometimes, server load increase or may be server slow down, then function code run multiple time when the user makes only one request, and  i don't understand why this happens.

ex. suppose in my code have 10 lines then it execute 1 to 5 and agian same code execute 1 to 5

Comment: can you share some code snippet?

Comment: public String genxml(some parameters)  {

Comment: public String genxml( some parametres )
{
DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

//
code for creating xml file 

//

Comment: TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance(); 
      Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(); 
      transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");  
      StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(); 
      StreamResult result = new StreamResult(sw);
      DOMSource source = new DOMSource(docss); 
      transformer.transform(source, result);
      String xmlString = sw.toString();       
      FileWriter fw1=new FileWriter(curfile,false);
      BufferedWriter bw1 = new BufferedWriter(fw1); 
      bw1.write(xmlString); 
      bw1.flush();

Comment: // then we call  soap web service have another methode in diffrent class  there we send created xml 

// bellow sample code for web service calling

DecryptEcrypte ed=new  DecryptEcrypte();     
String ecntext=ed.encryptXML(createdxml.toString());


 URL url = new URL(web service url);
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection)connection;
    ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    String xmlInput="<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' ---

Comment: ---standard xml
    xmlInput+="</tem:syncsubmitrequest></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>";
    byte[] buffer = new byte[xmlInput.length()];
    buffer = xmlInput.getBytes();
    bout.write(buffer);
   
    httpConn.setConnectTimeout(5000);
    OutputStream out = httpConn.getOutputStream();
    out.write(b);
    out.close();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(httpConn.getInputStream());
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);
    while ((responseString = in.readLine()) != null) {
    outputString = outputString + responseString;
    }

Comment: //  then cntrol return main methode

// here and web service return data into xml formate 

// we use some db insertion updation and redirect ot another page

Comment: Next time please edit the question by using the 'edit' button below it